# Creating a failover route in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-5, mvcroutehandler

I would like it if any Url that is not found is sent to my "Home" controller. And I mean like total garbage urls passed in Like SomeDomain/ThisIsNotAController/Goober/adsfasdf1?spacerocket.
A 404 error is just confusing to many people.

How do I map a route to say Home/Index if all others fail. I know you can do this in Rails.
Thanks in advance. and yes I did search for this, but I guess I don't know what to ask for

TW

Comment: Here's some ideas http://setiabud.blogspot.fi/2013/04/handling-404-error-in-aspnet-mvc.html?m=1

Answer (score 1):

You could use custom errors in the `web.config` file for this purpose by specifying an action method in the controller you wish...

```
public ActionResult NotFound(string aspxerrorpath)
{
    LogManager.Current.LogError(aspxerrorpath);
    Response.StatusCode = 404;
    return View();
}
```

Create the view as you normally would and then add the custom errors element in the `web.config` file...

```
<customErrors allowNestedErrors="true" mode="On">
   <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Your_Controller/NotFound"/>
</customErrors>
```